# Java SimpleDateFormat is parsing wrong dates

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have written the following code snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
 sdf.setLenient(false);
 currentString = currentString.trim();
 try{
    Date date = sdf.parse(currentString);
 } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    return ""; 
 }
```

I am expecting it to parse the date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` ie. it should parse date like `2013-10-28`.

Though it is working fine, it is also parsing wrong inputs like **2013-10-28aaab**. Ideally it should throw the exception when such kind of illegal date is given.

How can I restrict such illegal Date Patterns?

Comment: You code such way. You are catching the exception and returning `""`  ,Why ?

Comment: @Suresh: The contract for my method is to return empty String, if the Date is invalid. Anyways the problem is with parsing part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

use a regex to match the input

something like

```
"/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/"
```

Comment: Is there no way to do with SimpleDateFormat itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that this is the expected behaviour of `DateFormat`. From the JavaDoc of `parse`: _Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string._

Answer (score 0):

Just check the String length.  BTW, you should set lenient to true, otherwise non valid dates (2013-02-31) will be allowed.

Comment: That's not true. Lenient is opposite of strict, so setting lenient to false makes parsing strict, not allowing the parsing of dates like 2013-02-31.

Comment: The length will not work. Date 2013-2-2 is also valid and has lesser length. I think the set lenient should be set to false not true.

Comment: @Enrichman: I think it won't work for usecases like 2013-2-2a